# "NOT IN" for Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have a MySQL query that I am trying to chain a "NOT IN" at the end of it.

Here is what it looks like in ruby using Active Record:

```
not_in = find_by_sql("SELECT parent_dimension_id FROM relations WHERE relation_type_id  = 6;").map(&:parent_dimension_id)

      joins('INNER JOIN dimensions ON child_dimension_id = dimensions.id')
          .where(relation_type_id: model_relation_id,
                 parent_dimension_id: sub_type_ids,
                 child_dimension_id: model_type)
          .where.not(parent_dimension_id: not_in)
```

So the SQL query I'm trying to do looks like this:

```
INNER JOIN dimensions ON child_dimension_id = dimensions.id
WHERE relations.relation_type_id = 5 
AND relations.parent_dimension_id 
NOT IN(SELECT parent_dimension_id FROM relations WHERE relation_type_id  = 6);
```

Can someone confirm to me what I should use for that query?
do I chain on where.not ?

Answer (score 3):

If you really do want

```
SELECT parent_dimension_id
FROM relations
WHERE relation_type_id = 6
```

as a subquery, you just need to convert that SQL to an ActiveRecord relation:

```
Relation.select(:parent_dimension_id).where(:relation_type_id => 6)
```

then use that as a value in a `where` call the same way you'd use an array:

```
not_parents = Relation.select(:parent_dimension_id).where(:relation_type_id => 6)

Relation.joins('...')
        .where(relation_type_id: model_relation_id, ...)
        .where.not(parent_dimension_id: not_parents)
```

When you use an ActiveRecord relation as a value in a `where` and that relation selects a single column:

```
r = M1.select(:one_column).where(...)
M2.where(:column => r)
```

ActiveRecord is smart enough to inline `r`'s SQL as an `in (select one_column ...)` rather than doing two queries.

You could probably replace your:

```
joins('INNER JOIN dimensions ON child_dimension_id = dimensions.id')
```

with a simpler `joins(:some_relation)` if your relations are set up too.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed where clauses with values or arrays of values, in which case they will be translated into `in (?)` clauses.

Thus, the last part of your query could contain a mapping:

```
.where.not(parent_dimension_id:Relation.where(relation_type_id:6).map(&:parent_dimension_id))
```

Or you can prepare a statement

```
.where('parent_dimension_id not in (?)', Relation.where(relation_type_id:6).map(&:parent_dimension_id) )
```

which is essentially exactly the same thing

Comment: If you `where.not(parent_dimension_id: Relation.where(...).select(:parent_dimension_id))` AR will use a subquery (`parent_dimension_id not in (select parent_dimension_id from ...)`) rather than two queries with an intermediate Ruby array.

Comment: I've not tested this, but you are apparently right. Make this an answer and I'll drop mine :)